# Powershell incorrectly parsing JSON from REST API

Tags: powershell

So this is pretty much my first Powershell script and I've been struggling to perform a couple operations.  I am trying to pull data from one REST API and send it to another.  I can perform the two operations fine using Insomnia REST but I was trying to automate with Powershell.  Currently the relevant parts of my code look like this.

```
$infoToAdd = Invoke-RestMethod "$GetUrl"
$infoToAddJson = $infoToAdd | ConvertTo-Json -Depth 6 -Compress

$successfulRequest = Invoke-RestMethod "$PostUrl" -Method 'Post' -Body 
    $infoToAddJson -ContentType "application/json"
```

I call this in a loop and it works sometimes other times it does not.  I've tried not converting to JSON but it also failed immediately and I believe it automatically gets parsed to a Powershell Object.  I have confirmed that operations that failed in Powershell succeed with Insomnia REST.  I'm not sure if its the data itself.  There is nesting at least 4 layers deep and possible non-ASCII.  But I am also not sure if there is something I'm missing in my script.  The object I receive from my first call looks roughly like, at least in Insomnia,

```
{
  "0": {
      "_id": "3434123sdff23rf",
      "displayName": "Display Name",
      "name": "Name",
      "updatedDate": "2017-07-14T08:00:08.692Z",
      "createdDate": "2017-07-14T07:17:18.824Z",
      "array": [
        "String",
        "String2"
      ],
      text: "hello from blog town\n\nhello again\npath"C:\\Users\\" & 
        \"com\"actions more words\n\n end"
    },
  ...
}
```

Comment: If nothing else your `text` field is not properly escaped. `"C:` should be `\"C:` and `Users\\" &` should be `Users\\\" &`. Not sure if that's a typo, or actual invalid data.

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply.  Deleted text property and it appears to be running.  Now just trying to figure out why it would work with Insomnia and not Powershell.  But it looks like this isn't a Powershell issue.